# Run application as user?

Tags: deployment, runas, wmic

I have to deploy some applications in a domain and would like to use WMIC for that. My problem is that I can't run the application as the profile user (without having the password), but just as admin. Is there something like "su username -c my_command" (linux), which works for windows? Thanks a lot!

Regards,
Joseph

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if that's going to fix it, but

```
runas /user:<username> <command>
```

That lets you run commands as a different user

Comment: Unfortunately that'd also ask for the user password, which is not a very good idea :) I guess I'll have to use GPOs for this.